# opening directories like "THIS PC" or "NETWORK" from file manager

Tags: command, prompt

Is it possible to open "THIS PC" or "NETWORK" from the file manager using cmd? If yes, then how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible:

```
C:\>explorer shell:MyComputerFolder
C:\>explorer shell:NetworkPlacesFolder
```

Reference: [look here](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/shell-commands-to-access-the-special-folders/)

Comment: But the system can't find the specified path, that is,  for the following commands the system cannot identify explorer shell:

C:\>explorer shell:MyComputerFolder
C:\>explorer shell:NetworkPlacesFolder.                           What am I supposed to do? Please help.

Comment: About which Windows Version are you talking? I assume it is Windows 10, correct?

Comment: Yes it is a Windows 10 machine

Comment: What are you exactly typing into cmd? You know that C:\> means just that is the command prompt? So just open cmd and type "explorer shell:NetworkPlacesFolder" (without quotes) and press enter.

Comment: Yes, now I could execute the command properly. Thanks a lot!!!!